# Optimizing xmrig

Tags: mining, cpu-mining, linux, random-x, xmrig

I am mining Monero with **xmrig 5.11.1**. I am using an **AMD Ryzen 1950** cpu on **Ubuntu Linux 20.04**. I am trying to optimize my mining.

This is the output of the “h”. It shows an “anomaly” in threads 12, 13, 14, and 15. Their hash rate is much higher, 380 vs 160 as on the other threads.

```
[2020-06-09 14:19:32.047] speed 10s/60s/15m 5317.3 5378.0 5393.6 H/s max 5415.6 H/s
|    CPU # | AFFINITY | 10s H/s | 60s H/s | 15m H/s |
|        0 |        0 |   158.6 |   160.6 |   161.1 |
|        1 |        1 |   157.9 |   160.7 |   161.2 |
|        2 |        2 |   156.8 |   159.5 |   160.1 |
|        3 |        3 |   156.6 |   159.2 |   159.9 |
|        4 |        4 |   156.4 |   159.4 |   160.0 |
|        5 |        5 |   156.2 |   159.3 |   160.1 |
|        6 |        6 |   152.2 |   157.9 |   159.4 |
|        7 |        7 |   156.2 |   159.5 |   160.2 |
|        8 |        8 |   158.8 |   161.9 |   162.7 |
|        9 |        9 |   159.5 |   161.9 |   162.6 |
|       10 |       10 |   158.5 |   161.7 |   162.2 |
|       11 |       11 |   159.0 |   161.9 |   162.7 |
|       12 |       12 |   335.2 |   370.7 |   380.9 |
|       13 |       13 |   330.9 |   370.0 |   380.9 |
|       14 |       14 |   333.0 |   370.3 |   380.9 |
|       15 |       15 |   333.0 |   370.5 |   380.9 |
|       16 |       16 |   156.1 |   158.8 |   159.6 |
|       17 |       17 |   157.2 |   159.7 |   160.3 |
|       18 |       18 |   156.6 |   159.6 |   160.3 |
|       19 |       19 |   157.0 |   160.0 |   160.6 |
|       20 |       20 |   157.1 |   160.1 |   160.8 |
|       21 |       21 |   157.6 |   160.0 |   161.1 |
|       22 |       22 |   158.5 |   160.2 |   160.4 |
|       23 |       23 |   156.9 |   159.6 |   160.6 |
|       24 |       24 |   157.6 |   161.2 |   162.4 |
|       25 |       25 |   158.6 |   162.0 |   162.8 |
|       26 |       26 |   158.6 |   161.8 |   162.5 |
|       27 |       27 |   158.9 |   161.7 |   162.4 |
|        - |        - |  5109.8 |  5329.5 |  5389.7 |
[2020-06-09 14:19:47.192] speed 10s/60s/15m 5109.8 5329.5 5389.7 H/s max 5415.6 H/s
```

I don’t believe I have anything special in my config.json doing this. But I’d love to cause all the other threads to mine accordingly with those high hash rates, too.
I have an AMD Ryzen 1950 with 32 threads, as you see I am using 0 – 27 to mine. The other 4 are for me to do whatever. I can adjust accordingly if I have to.

Below, in my config.json, most of it is default created by xmrig when I ran it for the first time, it filled in a lot of defaults I realize I probably don’t need.
The only thing I changed was the  “rx” under the “cpu” to specify those 28 threads. The priority of 2 is just something I added as an experiment to fine-tune. I’m not married to that. Also, I changed my asm to “ryzen” and hugepages to true.

I am also using huge pages as suggested here https://xmrig.com/docs/miner/hugepages#onegb-huge-pages.
And randomx_boost from the same source.

```
wrmsr -a 0xc0011022 0x510000
wrmsr -a 0xc001102b 0x1808cc16
wrmsr -a 0xc0011020 0
wrmsr -a 0xc0011021 0x40
```

And here is the whole config.json:

```
{
    "api": {
        "id": null,
        "worker-id": null
    },
    "http": {
        "enabled": false,
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": 0,
        "access-token": null,
        "restricted": true
    },
    "autosave": true,
    "background": false,
    "colors": true,
    "randomx": {
        "init": -1,
        "mode": "auto",
        "1gb-pages": true,
        "rdmsr": true,
        "wrmsr": true,
        "numa": true
    },
    "cpu": {
        "enabled": true,
        "huge-pages": true,
        "hw-aes": null,
        "priority": null,
        "memory-pool": false,
        "yield": false,
        "asm": "ryzen",
        "argon2-impl": null,
        "astrobwt-max-size": 550,
        "astrobwt-avx2": false,
        "argon2": [0, 16, 1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 4, 20, 5, 21, 6, 22, 7, 23, 8, 24, 9, 25, 10, 26, 11, 27, 12, 28, 13, 29, 14, 30, 15, 31],
        "astrobwt": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
        "rx": [
            [2, 0],
            [2, 1],
            [2, 2],
            [2, 3],
            [2, 4],
            [2, 5],
            [2, 6],
            [2, 7],
            [2, 8],
            [2, 9],
            [2, 10],
            [2, 11],
            [2, 12],
            [2, 13],
            [2, 14],
            [2, 15],
            [2, 16],
            [2, 17],
            [2, 18],
            [2, 19],
            [2, 20],
            [2, 21],
            [2, 22],
            [2, 23],
            [2, 24],
            [2, 25],
            [2, 26],
            [2, 27]
        ],
        "cn": [
            [1, 0],
            [1, 1],
            [1, 2],
            [1, 3],
            [1, 4],
            [1, 5],
            [1, 6],
            [1, 7],
            [1, 8],
            [1, 9],
            [1, 10],
            [1, 11],
            [1, 12],
            [1, 13],
            [1, 14],
            [1, 15]
        ],
        "cn-heavy": [
            [1, 0],
            [1, 1],
            [1, 4],
            [1, 5],
            [1, 8],
            [1, 9],
            [1, 12],
            [1, 13]
        ],
        "cn-lite": [
            [1, 0],
            [1, 16],
            [1, 1],
            [1, 17],
            [1, 2],
            [1, 18],
            [1, 3],
            [1, 19],
            [1, 4],
            [1, 20],
            [1, 5],
            [1, 21],
            [1, 6],
            [1, 22],
            [1, 7],
            [1, 23],
            [1, 8],
            [1, 24],
            [1, 9],
            [1, 25],
            [1, 10],
            [1, 26],
            [1, 11],
            [1, 27],
            [1, 12],
            [1, 28],
            [1, 13],
            [1, 29],
            [1, 14],
            [1, 30],
            [1, 15],
            [1, 31]
        ],
        "cn-pico": [
            [2, 0],
            [2, 16],
            [2, 1],
            [2, 17],
            [2, 2],
            [2, 18],
            [2, 3],
            [2, 19],
            [2, 4],
            [2, 20],
            [2, 5],
            [2, 21],
            [2, 6],
            [2, 22],
            [2, 7],
            [2, 23],
            [2, 8],
            [2, 24],
            [2, 9],
            [2, 25],
            [2, 10],
            [2, 26],
            [2, 11],
            [2, 27],
            [2, 12],
            [2, 28],
            [2, 13],
            [2, 29],
            [2, 14],
            [2, 30],
            [2, 15],
            [2, 31]
        ],
        "rx/wow": [0, 16, 1, 17, 2, 18, 3, 19, 4, 20, 5, 21, 6, 22, 7, 23, 8, 24, 9, 25, 10, 26, 11, 27, 12, 28, 13, 29, 14, 30, 15, 31],
        "cn/0": false,
        "cn-lite/0": false,
        "rx/arq": "rx/wow",
        "rx/keva": "rx/wow"
    },
    "opencl": {
        "enabled": false,
        "cache": true,
        "loader": null,
        "platform": "AMD",
        "adl": true,
        "astrobwt": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "intensity": 256,
                "threads": [-1, -1]
            }
        ],
        "cn": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "intensity": 864,
                "worksize": 8,
                "strided_index": [1, 2],
                "threads": [-1, -1],
                "unroll": 8
            }
        ],
        "cn-heavy": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "intensity": 864,
                "worksize": 8,
                "strided_index": [1, 2],
                "threads": [-1, -1],
                "unroll": 8
            }
        ],
        "cn-lite": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "intensity": 1728,
                "worksize": 8,
                "strided_index": [1, 2],
                "threads": [-1, -1],
                "unroll": 8
            }
        ],
        "cn-pico": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "intensity": 1728,
                "worksize": 8,
                "strided_index": [2, 2],
                "threads": [-1, -1],
                "unroll": 8
            }
        ],
        "cn/2": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "intensity": 864,
                "worksize": 8,
                "strided_index": [2, 2],
                "threads": [-1, -1],
                "unroll": 8
            }
        ],
        "rx": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "intensity": 576,
                "worksize": 8,
                "threads": [-1, -1],
                "bfactor": 6,
                "gcn_asm": true,
                "dataset_host": false
            }
        ],
        "cn/0": false,
        "cn-lite/0": false
    },
    "cuda": {
        "enabled": false,
        "loader": null,
        "nvml": true
    },
    "donate-level": 5,
    "donate-over-proxy": 1,
    "log-file": null,
    "pools": [
        {
            "algo": null,
            "coin": null,
            "url": "pool.supportxmr.com:443",
            "user": "46WSYHD27TDjL7Shu7fVBdWMNMsik5E2n1bXcw4g6Aum8EtqoXwaqDu2Cad5YrfrgTfwm8RcUvbf4Gzb2EZF4wEJ46T8hjy",
            "pass": "JM-xmrig-miner",
            "rig-id": null,
            "nicehash": false,
            "keepalive": true,
            "enabled": true,
            "tls": true,
            "tls-fingerprint": null,
            "daemon": false,
            "socks5": null,
            "self-select": null
        }
    ],
    "print-time": 60,
    "health-print-time": 60,
    "retries": 5,
    "retry-pause": 5,
    "syslog": false,
    "tls": {
        "enabled": false,
        "protocols": null,
        "cert": null,
        "cert_key": null,
        "ciphers": null,
        "ciphersuites": null,
        "dhparam": null
    },
    "user-agent": null,
    "verbose": 0,
    "watch": true
}
```

Comment: each rhread need 2mb of cache memory, if you select more threads than a half of your mb chache memory the hash rate decays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMD Ryzen has 32 threads but 16 cores. When I cut down the number of xmrigs' threads to 16. Each of the produced at a much higher rate. More than double of running 2 mining threads on each core.